# "You tell me" questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I don't think this is an acceptable question, but it doesn't seem to have an appropriate way to close it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097449/i-need-to-know-the-output-of-this-c-code-please/23097492#23097492

I know this has come up a lot since the recent changes with close vote reasons. I also see this has been asked about before, but the answer -- close as not a real question -- is now irrelevant ([Close reason: "You tell me"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64516/close-reason-you-tell-me)).

The problem is this question is clear, specific, programming-related, reproducible, and not a direct request for an off-site resource, but it's still not really a great question since it's so trivial to find the answer.

You can see people are itching to close questions like these, but they can't agree on why. Is this intended?

Comment: This is usually the case with pointless and ridiculously low-effort questions.

Comment: I'd even vote to _delete_ the said question.

Comment: [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097449/i-need-to-know-the-output-of-this-c-code-please/23097492#comment35305384_23097449) would further indicate what you're inviting by answering such posts.

Comment: BTW, the question is gone now.

Comment: I second to delete said question >:O

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is not an acceptable question and it **must** be closed.

The question, although programming related,

- does not add value (you need to *feed* the program to the compiler and write the output in your answer)
- doesn't deserve an answer -- even if OPs compiler is broken, an online compiler could be used

I'd close this as:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient
>   information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more
>   detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

or even by specifying a custom close reason:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about compiling
>   the code in question to determine the output.  Use a compiler, please.

Answering such posts only leads to even worse posts.

It would be perfectly OK if a question were to ask about something specific in the output that the OP thought would have produced a different result or worked in a different manner.

Comment: For "Why do I get such an output" questions, I hope you meant questions that actually ask specific questions about understanding the code, not just a blanket "Here's code, here's the output, why am I getting this?"), as I'd close that as unclear or too broad - no idea to even start explaining - it can be anywhere from understanding basic syntax to 'complicated' logic.

Comment: @Dukeling Of course, it was implicit that the question asks about a specific behavior in that case.  Not like a code dump and output to explain.  But more like, something specific that the OP thought would result into something but doesn't.  (Updated the post to reflect that.)