# New "no effort" closing reason?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

**Note:** I am aware of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40971/new-reason-for-closing-insufficient-effort). I want to ask a different question, even though the wording is the same. The lack of "effort" I am talking about does not lie in the formulation of the OP's question.

As you can see in [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8998/closing-questions-that-show-no-effort-official-policy?cb=1), a lot of people on math.SE think we should close the questions which **show no effort toward a solution and seem to be plain copied/pasted homework**.

I personally would not close them. But I understand why some people think this way. And if they're a majority...

The problem is that none of the listed closing reasons apply to this case, as they currently stand.

I am aware of Jeff Atwood♦'s answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40971/new-reason-for-closing-insufficient-effort). Maybe it does it for some other SE sites.  but it does not work for math.SE. The "no effort" questions under consideration there are real questions, make perfect sense, and can easily be answered. So by no means they can be closed for not being real questions.

I am not sure how things work here in these matters. But I think there should be a sort of survey asking whether we should actually closed "no effort" questions. And if a majority say yes, then:

**Question:** Would it be possible to create a new closing reason for "no effort" questions?

Comment: Why would "not a real question" not fit the bill? We have certain requirements for a question. Doing your homework is one. If that is not done, or no effort is shown, I would regard that as the question being "incomplete".

Comment: @Bart I see your point. But the wording "not a real question" does not apply. I see why, with a little stretch, "incomplete" would apply. But I think the questions I am pointing at are very different, in essence, from the questions the "not a real question" closing reasons point at.

Comment: It surprises me that the Math SE community would pull a complete 180 on this issue. I left Math SE because a lot of the users--including the diamond moderators--were not only too happy to not only answer "no effort" questions, but shout down anyone who dared suggest that the person asking the question actually try something first.

Comment: @JackManey I have not been active on MSE for a long time. But I have never seen anyone shout down anybody for this reason. Come back!

Comment: @Jack I'm not exactly active on Math, but every time I browse there I notice the same thing happening. It makes a very stark contrast with Physics, and in fact we occasionally get people whining about they post no-effort homework-like questions on Math and get them answered without complaints. To each site their own, I guess...

Comment: @julien - Absolutely not. After having a temper tantrum thrown at me by a diamond moderator on Math.SE, I asked to have my account deleted there. I refuse to even consider going back until they start aggressively closing and deleting "plz do this problum for me, kthxbai" questions. I've done enough babysitting to last a lifetime, thank you very much.

Comment: @JackManey I see. Then it is certainly better like that.

Comment: @julien - Well, you're welcome to it.

Comment: @JackManey I did not mean that in a sarcastic way or anything. I just meant that if the reasons you mention upset you that much, it is probably better not to come back as there is indeed a lot of baby-sitting going on.