# Why was "too localized" removed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Many times I would "Close Vote" a question for being too localized, for example

"oops, I forgot to put a semi-colon at the end of a line"

These questions are unlikely to help anyone else, is another pathway available now to get rid of them?

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns

Comment: The post explaining this has a *lot* of questions/answers about it. this reason is now in the off topic section, if i recall correctly.

Comment: It was removed because the SO staff decided to remove it. Stupid decision.

Comment: Off topic doesn't cover it. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304229/the-value-provided-for-the-report-parameter-is-not-valid-for-its-type) for example is a well explained question that is totally on topic, however the solution was he forgot to add `[` and `]` around the parameter. Normally I would close this as "Too localised" but now it doesn't fit any close reason. So it is a useless question that will never help anyone but will remain open. Maybe the [Obsolete tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185329/can-we-have-a-red-status-tag-for-obsolete) would fix it.

Comment: @Hiroto I can't find any reason in the off topic section for questions about typos or small mistakes (In SO).