# Minimal effort flags?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, flags, close-reasons

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525513/trying-to-understand-opencvs-cvreduce) post it just seems like the OP is trying to get someone to do his homework for him. I tried to flag it but it didnt really fit any of the reasons. Is this classified as a *very low quality* post? What's the best way to handle something like this?

This [New reason for closing: Insufficient Effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40971/new-reason-for-closing-insufficient-effort) sounds reasonable but there is no option when I tried to flag it

Comment: did u try toooo broad?

Comment: @Azik *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.* that just doesn't seem to fit it right. I mean all he wants is a piece code, hes just to lazy to do it himself

Comment: Maybe "Off Topic", " Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist"

Comment: If the OP really needs a simple piece of code with good explanation, then it should be a duplicate which should be discussed in the site earlier.If the concept is not discussed earlier and then there is no need of flagging.

Comment: @Matt I get this description for "Off Topic" on the choice list *This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.* Has its definition been expanded?

Comment: @TsSkTo: If you click the "Off Topic" choice, it should change to a further pane of options. It does for me at least, but that *might* be dependant on reputation.

Comment: Yup, that did it. I must have been distracted by all the unicorns in my office. @Matt if you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: -1 Poster must show minimal effort.

Comment: i agree with @TsSkTo. There should be a `do my homework` flag or `insufficient effort`. I guess we are using the `must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved` as its the only one available as it stands

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "Off Topic" which states that:

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

... would be suitable for this.