# How can a (new) user tell if/when a question will be migrated?

Tags: support, migration, off-topic

A few days ago, I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487328/how-can-i-allow-use-of-the-certificate-store-on-windows-7) which is currently flagged as on hold, due to being off-topic. According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) meta question, a migration will/can/might happen if five users vote to close and at least four of them suggest the same site.

The only information I can find on my question is that five users voted to close, and four suggested Super User.

So my question is how can I determine for myself when this question will be migrated? I don't see any documentation on other requirements to be met. Maybe a moderator on the origin site needs to approve the migration? Perhaps the destination site needs to approve it? Without more information on the question, I really have no idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those users that voted chose the 'suggested option'

[image: suggest super user]

Not the 'migrate' option.

[image: Migrate to super user]

So your question will not migrate at all.

You have three options:

1. Ask a new question on Super User, delete the one in Stack Overflow.
2. Flag for moderator attention and ask for a migration to Super User.
3. Find 3 users to re-open your question and 5 to close vote for migration to Super User.

You best option is number 1.

The reason for having those different options is because migration is hard to get right (we don't want [to migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225006/add-a-dont-migrate-crap-migration-path-to-all-sites)), specially when the users that are close voting are not seasoned users on the target site. In those cases you better not choose migration but only suggest a different site. It is up to the OP in that case to check the help center of the target site, study the tags and ask on their meta to make sure the question is on-topic on that site.

Comment: Makes sense now, in principle. I'm surprised that the answer is, effectively, "cross-post to manually migrate it". I'm more surprised that there is a distinction between "migrate this" and "we sorta kinda think this should maybe be migrated". However, I suppose if you have a historical problem with low quality (read: low effort) questions, manual action by the OP would be a low barrier to keeping them out.

Comment: That summarizes it pretty well @joel. If you search for migrate on any meta site you'll hve plenty to read and you'll find all opinions possible

Comment: If you're question is migrated, I believe you get a notification at the top of that as well :)

Answer (score 5):

Migration is also closure. If the vote to migrate had been successful, the message would have been migrated at the time it was closed. That it's "on hold" and not migrated indicates that in a few days it will transition to "closed" and, likely, in a few months be auto-deleted.

At this point, the only likely way to get it migrated would be for it to be re-opened then re-closed with the votes to migrate. You're better off just re-posting it on the correct site. You *might* flag it for moderator attention and use the "other" option to make your case to get it migrated, but the moderator may not agree.

Comment: Positive score on-hold doesn't get roomba'd IIRC.

Comment: Note that moderator-flag migration can happen at any time.

Comment: @Mat: true enough, although I think the requisite downvotes will come along in time.

Comment: @Nathan: I though a moderator had to re-open the question in order to migrate. Granted, the two actions would be done within seconds of each other.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce: I don't believe so, but I could be mistaken. Usual advice I've heard is to first make sure the question is rightly closed, then migrate-flag it.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce: [Example](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/68102/revisions).