# Could we make the migration search function for moderators be made available to regular users?

Tags: feature-request, migration, moderator-abilities, migration-path-request

This question was [originally asked on Writing Meta](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/community-specific-reasons-for-closing-only-shows-elu-and-writing-meta-se-optio) but I decided to make it a feature request and ask it here after some advice from a Writers mod.

I was wondering if we could make the migration search function for moderators be made available to regular users? One reason for closing is that the question should belong on a different SE site. The pop-up box only gives you a couple possible sites to migrate the question to (depending on what site the question was asked on). For example, in Writing SE, it gives you the migration options of Writing Meta and EL&U. (see picture at the bottom)

Could we include a search bar to pick any SE site to migrate to instead of just a couple of options? Most of the time, the question should be moved to the relevant options in the pop-up box - but there are oddball questions that should be moved to a different SE site than the given options. I understand that moderators have this ability, but why not give it to regular users? It would not hurt - it would actually make things more convenient.

(example)

[image]

Comment: probably relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225006/add-a-dont-migrate-crap-migration-path-to-all-sites

Comment: No, because most migrations are misguided and inappropriate.